# Holder continuity of Poisson equation with divergence free drift

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am interested in the following PDE.
Suppose $u_m$ is a smooth solution of a elliptic equation of the form

$$ -\Delta u_m(x) + a_m(x) \cdot \nabla u_m(x) = f_m(x) \qquad B_1 $$ with $ u_m=0 $ on $\partial B_1$.  $B_1 $ is the open unit ball centered at the origin in $ R^N$.
$a_m(x)$ is a smooth divergence free drift whose suppose is contained in $B_\frac{1}{m}$ and whose $L^N $ norm is constant (but maybe not small).  Here $f_m$ is bounded in, say $L^\infty$.   My question is can one obtain uniform Holder bounds on $u_m$?

I know these problems are very well studied lately but I am having trouble googling for the correct answer.    thanks for any remarks
Craig